# USB devices disconnect and reconnect, plus random video flickering issue

Tags: usb, graphics-card, connection

All of a sudden, whenever I connect a USB device, such as a WiFi dongle or a pen-drive, it randomly disconnects and reconnects. This happens way too often.

I have disabled the feature where Windows 10 tries to turn off USB devices to save power.

Also, whenever I play a video, it flickers randomly and seems like each frame is cut into several horizontal sections.

I have tried replacing the GPU and also the PSU, but the issues persist.

- Processor: AMD Fx6300
- Mobo: Gigabyte 970 gaming
  _ RAM: 16GB
- GPU: Sapphire R9 270 | (tried with Sapphire R7 265 too)
- PSU: Thermaltek Litpower 550 | (tried with replacing with another Thermaltek Litpower 550)

What could possibly be the problem/solution here?

Comment: Guess: Difficult to determine hardware fault on the motherboard. First thing is to check capacitors for leaks/bulging.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue only happen on this windows 10 PC, I Think the issue could be related to the USB drives.

try to uninstall the USB drive and re-install the USB drive, and update it to the latest one.

Or, try to use the Microsoft tool to fix the issue.
click the website and download the tool:
***Find and fix problems with devices and hardware***
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2970908/how-to-use-microsoft-easy-fix-solutions

Hope it could help you.